# MySql restore command throwing default values

Tags: mysql, linux, restore

I am trying to restore a database in a remote RDS instance from a Linux box. Below is my command:

```
sudo mysql –h host.amazonaws.com –u username –p password databasename < backupfile.sql
```

MySql version 14.14. When I enter the above command, I get to see all the default values below. And the database does not get restored.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

I see default values. Also the database is not getting restored. Command seems to be correct. Not sure what's wrong. any help?

**UPDATE:**

I edited my command to be like below:

```
mysql -u username -p -h hostname.amazonaws.com databasename < backupfile.sql
```

I see the below error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa' at line 1
```

Also last time the command did not prompt for password but this time it prompted for password and threw me the above error.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.*

Comment: `sudo` shouldn't be necessary for a database restore.

Comment: ok I will remove the screenshot and add the message fully

Comment: The screenshot in this case doesn't really help at all. That's just what happens when you use `mysql` without any arguments or a bad argument.

Comment: Also the message does not give me anything useful. Like..no error emssages

Comment: Try this without `sudo`. Database access is not controlled by your current user.

Comment: Tried without sudo and still seeing the same default values :(

Comment: Can you do that without `sudo` and without `<` reading from the file? You need to verify those credentials work before going further. Also try with [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) if applicable. Does the host resolve?

Comment: You can't have a space between `-p` and the password.

Comment: So, that remote RDS instance port is not open to mysqlworkbench. So I had to restore only using command line. I checked the credentials and its working fine. Only the restore is not working

Comment: @Barmar still seeing same issue

Comment: edited the question with different command and error

Comment: The second error looks like it's because there are error messages in the backup file, rather than SQL.

Comment: You might have had the same problem with `-p` when using `mysqldump`. And then you redirected stderr to the dump file, so the error message was written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This shows that your dump file contains error messages from a failed `mysqldump` command.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
> OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa' at line 1

In other words, whenever you created the backup, it did not back up any data. The mysqldump command issued an error and aborted. You have no data in your file to restore.

I hope you still have the original database, because you need to create a new backup and check that it is successful.